# Not getting the iterations i want

Tags: python-2.7, list, iteration

I have been working on this for some time and I cant get the iterations I want from the loops I coded. The code starts by calling headerBody10() and appending the output to a list, dist. There are two columns in the list, column 0 in dist is the FROM data, and column 1 is TO data. By the time the dist list is appended it is a list of lists.

I want to find all the rows of data where the FROM is similar to the TO, or which roads have an intersection. I want this code to run each FROM through all the TO data and so far I have just the first row of FROM being run through all the TO rows. So the incrementor m is the FROM column and and n is the TO column. So the question is how can I make every row of FROM be run through every row of TO?

```
n = 0
m = 0
dist = []
match = []
for line in headerBody10():
    dist.append(line)
try:
    for data in dist:
        for line in data:
            if dist[n][1] in dist[m][0]:
                match.append([dist[n][1],dist[m][0],n,m])
            else:
                m = m + 1
    n = n + 1
except IndexError:
    print match
```

Here are some sample inputs:

```
26th St South,  Jct 13th St South
N-101 10th St,  Jct 23rd St NE
Central Ave,    Interstate 15
17Th St NE,         N-104 10th St N
N-60 10th Ave S,    End 4 lane
Fox Farm Rd ,       Flood Road
```

Here is the latest output, this output is from the else clause so not matches were found. m is iterating just fine but it stops before n can iterate.

```
I-15 Gore Hill       Concrete 1 0
I-15 Gore Hill       Fox Farm Rd 2 0
I-15 Gore Hill       13th St South 3 0
I-15 Gore Hill       23rd St NE 4 0
I-15 Gore Hill       Intererstate 15 5 0
I-15 Gore Hill       N-104 10th St N 6 0
I-15 Gore Hill       4 lane 7 0
I-15 Gore Hill       Flood Road 8 0
I-15 Gore Hill       Division 9 0
I-15 Gore Hill       6th St 10 0
I-15 Gore Hill       Concrete 11 0
```

Comment: Or a multidimensional array? So is you want all matches where n and m are 1 index off from each other? Also since you are trying to iterate over index its best to use `for i in range(0,n):  for j in range(0,m):`

Comment: @Edward I did the offset because I was trying to compare one row to the next row. I guess that doesn't make sense anymore ill change it.

Comment: give some outputs of maybe what you are getting and what you want

Comment: @ Edward ok ill do that right now

Comment: Maybe your n = n+1 needs to be indented one more time.

Comment: No that brings up two iterations per row of FROM not all the rows

Comment: I don't want the to's or n, to iterate until all the from or m, column have finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just take out the other n,m initialization and iteration (adding)

```
for n in range(0,len(dist)):
    for m in range(0,len(dist)):
        if dist[n][1] in dist[m][0]:
            match.append([dist[n][1],dist[m][0],n,m])
```

Comment: Also no need for exception handling of `try` as it will never go outside the dimensional index of the object